# Affinity Designer: Add emboss text to group with embossing?

Tags: affinity-designer

I apologize in advance for the awful title and for the long question. I just want to explain what I've done, since I'm new with Affinity Designer.

I'm trying to use the "Subtract" tool to subtract text from a group of squares.

My first step: I drew 2 squares, grouped them, and then added "emboss" to the group. So far it looks fine:

[image]

Now I want to add text so that it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFCox.png), but each square having one letter.

I started with one square, added the emboss, added the letter over the square, and used the "Subtract" tool. This is how I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFCox.png), which looks good. I assumed it would be the same process with group.

The problem is that when I do exact the same thing with the group above (the rectangle with the 2 grouped squares with the "emboss"), I get this. It seems to take both squares in the group, join them as one object, eliminate the emboss, and then do the "Subtract":

[image]

In any case, the end-result should be this, without the emboss in the middle:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an Affinity Design user, so this is a bit of a guess based on other vector image editors I have used, such as Illustrator and Inkscape. However, this should work in almost any vector software.

Subtract the letters from two separate shapes, not a group.

Move the two pieces together, and then group them.

Now apply your bevel and emboss effect to the group.

[image]

Comment: I tried it in Affinity Designer and it works.

Comment: @Vikas cool, thanks for confirming. Yeah, most vector software works much about the same for things like this, although the details differ.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *Erase* blend mode for the text layers. Move them in the shapes group and then apply the Emboss to the group. I think that's what you are trying to achieve:

[image]