# Affinity Designer: Add emboss to only 2 sides of a square?

Tags: affinity-designer

This is a follow-up to this question: [Affinity Designer: Add emboss text to group with embossing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/164808/affinity-designer-add-emboss-text-to-group-with-embossing/164810#164810)

I was able to group the three squares and subtract the letters from the group:
[image]

But now I want to add a slight "emboss" to the middle square so there's sort of a *division* between the middle square and the other two squares, but not as deep as the current embossing.

So I tried adding the "embossing' to the red middle square, but that adds the shade/embossing again, which makes it look odd since the red square already has the embossing from the group:
[image]

How can I add "embossing" to the red square, but only on the left and right sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new single gradient shape on the red square:

[image]

The gradient stops from left to right: black, white ,transparent, transparent, black. The shape has opacity 55% in the next result:

[image]

The corners are erased partially to avoid double shading. (This is a bitmap, sorry. But so is the bevel and emboss in Affinity Designer, too.)

To get the borders narrow enough easily it may be better to draw the slices separately.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not Affinity Designer specific, but should work with any vector software. How I would achieve this is to place two thin rectangles on top of the seam, one filled black and one white, and reduce their opacity. Duplicate for the other seam.

Here I'm just using your raster image to simulate this, and have zoomed in.

[image]

At normal size, it looks convincing.

[image]

Or maybe use some slightly wider rectangles, and if you feel the transition is too sharp you could apply a small amount of blur.

[image]

You could also experiment a bit with this. Perhaps add the seams to your group without the bevel and emboss effect first, then apply your main bevel and emboss effect to the group.